# angular js drag drop shopping cart item already is cart increment count

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My plnkr [url](http://plnkr.co/edit/oRCGKvh1AmA04V0NyPKs?p=preview)

my js code

```
$(function() {
          $("#catalog").accordion();
        });
        var App = angular.module('drag-and-drop', ['ngDragDrop']);
        App.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
          $scope.list1 = [{"name":"Axe","mrp":"$91","discount":"$81.00","quantity":1},{"name":"soaps","mrp":"10.00","discount":"2.00","quantity":1}];
          $scope.list4 = [];
          $scope.hideMe = function() {
            return $scope.list4.length > 0;
          }
        });
```

onclick + increment function

```
function ctrl($scope) {
          $scope.increment = function(item){
            item.quantity += 1;
          }
           $scope.minus = function(item){
            item.quantity -= 1;
          }
        }
```

1)How to append item already in basket increment count 
2)click + icon to increment if item already in the cart else add the item to cart

any idea friends